# how can I change groupID of maven file?

Tags: maven

I have parent pom.xml and two pom.xml files (one for frontend and one for backend) that are children pom.xml files. I am using maven version 4. I have already built these maven files using mvn clean install and the artifacts are published on corporate Nexus.

My Parent pom.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.replace.starters.ngboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-angular-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>spring-boot-angular-starter</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Angular Starter Project</description>


    <modules>
        <module>frontend</module>
        <module>backend</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Here, I want to change com.replace.starters.ngboot to com.somethingelse.starters.ngboot for group ID. I also
want to change name and description.

pom.xml for frontend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-angular-starter</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.replace.starters.ngboot</groupId>
    <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
    <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Here, I want to change groupID so that it matches with the parent pom.

This is my pom.xml for backend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-angular-starter</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.replace.starters.ngboot</groupId>
        <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I want to change groupID of the backend pom so that it matches with the parent pom.

How can I achieve this? I tried simply renaming groupId on the pom files and it did not work.

My error is: 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT not found on both frontend and backend pom.xml files.

Comment: there are probably dependencies between the modules that may still use the old groupdId - you can just edit them, just make sure you search and replace the texts across all pom.xml files in the project (replace ">old.group.id<" with ">new.group.id<" to not hit some old.group.id.subgroup as well)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Change the Artifact ID name directly in Pom.xml file where its mentioned as  </artifact ID> in the main files.

But be sure to keep the same name in frontend and backend files of Pom.xml also otherwise u will see errors.